# Remove name from array of countries

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I've an array of countries and I want to try and delete the element that I call it so that when I go back to the array it won't call it again.

```
randomFlag1 = names[Answer];
flag1Name = "Flags/" + myApp.FlagSet + "/" + names[Answer] + ".png";
Flag4.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(flag1Name, UriKind.Relative));
Flag4.Name = NameHolder.Text;
```

This is how I get the random name.

Comment: Why don't you use a List<T>? Makes it a lot easier to remove stuff. You could however, write a loop yourself over all the objects, and remove the object at the index of the found item.

Comment: You must post your full code. Which type of array this is?